# Unable to convert string... to string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to make a simple debuger in a view.. and I have the following:
[image]

I'm using Alamofire to make the request, receiving the data with `responseString` and then sending it with `App.log( response )` towards `debugViewController`'s `log`method which as you can see expects a string as well.

Now, trying to compile this returns an error which is very weird for me as I'm new to Swift. Cannot convert string to the argument type expected in `debugViewController.log()` which is in fact `String` as well ?

Please enlight me on this one.

Here you have the `debugViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class debugViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var debugTextField: UITextView!

    @IBAction func dismissDebug(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

     func log( data: String ) {
        debugTextField.text = data
    }

}
```

And here you can see how I make the call and send data:

```
Alamofire.request( .POST, API_URL, parameters: [ "action": "authenticate", "email": userEmail!, "password": userPassword! ] )
            .responseString { response in

                guard let value = response.result.value else
                {
                    return App.alert( "error", message: "Did not receive data")
                }

                guard response.result.error == nil else
                {
                    print( response.result.error )
                    return App.alert( "error", message: "An error occurred" )
                }

                App.log ( value )


        }
```

Comment: how is debugViewController defined? it seems you are invoking an instance method on the class itself

Comment: @giorashc updated my question.

Comment: Can you post the code where data is assigned a value? Also, check if data is not an optional. If it is then try unwrapping it like data!

Comment: If you're using response.result, it is of type anybject. Have you typecasted it to string. While sending it to App.log() ?

Comment: @iamyogish i have updated my question with the response part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`debugViewController` is a class (I advise you to start class names with a capital letter) and you are trying to invoke an instance method on the class itself, hence the error (as it actually expects an instance of type `debugViewController`).

You should keep an instance of the `debugViewController` after it is being created so you could call the log method on the instance rather than on the class

Comment: Ok, so in layman terms what I was doing wrong was that I was calling a dynamic method on a non-instantiated class right ? I mean, I don't have Swift background but I know some OOP. Regarding the camelCase stuff, I've just read that it's better to use camelCase pattern, but, seems like i got it wrong. Anyway, why is it if i change the func to static, I can't access the `debugTextField` in log method anymore ?

Comment: Yes @giorashc is right. You're calling an instance method of debugViewController. You can either create an instance or make the method log method as class method.

Comment: @edduvs You can't access the debugTextField in log method because, it's a property of an debugViewController class. And to access a property of a class you need to create an instance.

Comment: @iamyogish if I make the log as class method, I can't access the value from IBOutlet anymore ( debugTextField ). And now, it says `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, even though the string contains my JSON response. What's to be done ?

Comment: @edduvs Yes when you're calling the class functions you'll not be able to access the IBOutlets, because outlets are associated with the instance. And now "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" this is because you're trying to set the text of the textfield which is an outlet. And textfield is nil because you've not created a instance of the class.

Comment: @edduvs Better make the log function of the debugVC as a func instead of class func. And then create an instance of debugVC before calling debugViewController.log(data);

Comment: @iamyogish Could I have your skype for .. some additional details on how to do that ? What you write here has logic, but it's kind of hard to follow the instructions having less than a week of experience with swift. Asking because I have inited `let debug = debugViewController` in App class and it still returns that `nil` error.

Comment: @edduvs please drop in your skype id in comment I will contact you. Thanks

Comment: @edduvs check this tutotial about view controllers with swift 2: http://www.raywenderlich.com/115279/swift-2-tutorial-part-2-a-simple-ios-app. Let me know if it helps...

Comment: @iamyogish my skype is : sinner.haltrich